# как сохранить файлы на сервер?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```js
/ LOAD IMAGE
var fileCollection = [];
var formData = new FormData(fileCollection);
var files = [];
console.log(files);

$('.upload__add-photo').on('change', function(e){
 
  files=e.target.files;
  files2=e.target.files;
  console.log("--------after");
  console.log(files);
  $.each(files2, function(i, file){

    fileCollection.push(file);
 console.log("fileCollection");
 console.log(fileCollection);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 
 console.log("files");
 console.log(files);
    reader.onload = function(e){

      var template = '<div class="upload__box upload__your-photo">'+
                        '<img src="'+e.target.result+'">'+
                        '<div class="delete-photo" onclick="delPrewievPhoto($(this).parent().index(), $(this).parent())">Удалить</div>'+
                     '</div>';

      var valueBoxPhoto = $('.upload__your-photo').length;
   console.log("files onload");
   console.log(files);
   console.log("fileCollection onload")
   console.log(fileCollection);
      if(valueBoxPhoto > 1){
        $('.upload-btn-JS').hide();
      }

      if(valueBoxPhoto == 0){
        $('.upload-JS').prepend(template);
      } else {
        $('.upload__your-photo').eq(-1).after(template);
      }
    }
  })
  files=fileCollection;
  console.log("----------------");
  console.log(files);
  console.log("----------------");
})
console.log("end");
console.log(files);
function delPrewievPhoto(indexArray, currentItem){

  fileCollection.splice(indexArray, 1);
  currentItem.remove();
  console.log(fileCollection);
  if($('.upload__your-photo').length < 4){
    $('.upload-btn-JS').show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order__upload">
                  <div class="upload upload-JS">
                    <label class="upload-btn-JS">
                      <div class="upload__box upload__add-photo">
                        <input type="file" multiple name="images[]">
                        <div class="upload__plus"><span></span><span></span></div>
                        <div class="upload__text">Добавить фото</div>
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Как я поняла, за это отвечает e.target.files.

Comment: Какой именно сервер?

Comment: сервер php, чтобы попал в массив $_FILES при сабмите формы, у меня почему-то попадает последний загруженный файл. Как я поняла, это связано с event.target .